# Machine Learning for gesture recognition with Myo Armband

Tags: deep-learning, label, gesture, cntk, myo

I'm trying to develop a model to recognize new gestures with the Myo Armband. (It's an armband that possesses 8 electrical sensors and can recognize 5 hand gestures). I'd like to record the sensors' raw data for a new gesture and feed it to a model so it can recognize it.

I'm new to machine/deep learning and I'm using CNTK. I'm wondering what would be the best way to do it.

I'm struggling to understand how to create the trainer. The input data looks like something like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeA7k.png) I'm thinking about using 20 sets of these 8 values (they're between -127 and 127). So one label is the output of 20 sets of values.

I don't really know how to do that, I've seen tutorials where images are linked with their label but it's not the same idea. And even after the training is done, how can I avoid the model to recognize this one gesture whatever I do since it's the only one it's been trained for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to get you started would be to create 161 columns (8 columns for each of the 20 time steps + the designated label). You would rearrange the columns like

```
emg1_t01, emg2_t01, emg3_t01, ...,  emg8_t20, gesture_id
```

This will give you the right 2D format to use different algorithms in [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) as well as a feed forward neural network in CNTK. You would use the first 160 columns to predict the 161th one.

Once you have that working you can model your data to better represent the natural time series order it contains. You would move away from a 2D shape and instead create a 3D array to represent your data.

- The first axis shows the number of samples
- The second axis shows the number of time steps (20)
- The thirst axis shows the number of sensors (8)

With this shape you're all set to use a 1D convolutional model (CNN) in CNTK that traverses the time axis to learn local patterns from one step to the next.

You might also want to look into RNNs which are often used to work with time series data. However, RNNs are sometimes hard to train and a [recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.01271) suggests that CNNs should be the natural starting point to work with sequence data.

Comment: Thanks for the fast anwser ! I'll try this out

Comment: Don't forget to upvote the answer if you found it helpful and to accept it if it answered your question.

Comment: I don't have the voting privilege to upvote yet but I accepted it. Thanks !